# jQuery remove class item keeps coming back

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the situation.

I'm trying to remove an div class item based when the user clicks on a rating.

The problem I have is that every time I click on the item it goes away, however when I move the mouse the item that I removed comes back.

Here is my current code:

```
    <div class="star_'.($iPos+1).' ratings_stars ratings_vote" onmouseover="overRating(this);" onmouseout="outRating(this);" onClick="selectEmailRating(this);" ></div>
```

The above item is the div that is calling the JavaScript.  When I click on the rating I run the code that is in the following function below:

```
    function selectEmailRating(elem) {
        var star = elem;
        var rating = widget.data('fsr').rating;

        if($(star).attr('class') === 'star_'+ rating + ' ratings_stars ratings_over ratings_vote'){
          $(elem).andSelf().removeClass();
          $(star).attr('class', 'star_'+ rating + ' ratings_stars');
          $(star).attr('class').unbind('onmouseover').unbind('onmouseout');
        }


      function outRating(elem) {
          $(elem).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');  
          setRating($(elem).parent()); 
      }

      function overRating(elem) {
           $(elem).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over'); 
           $(elem).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
       }

       function setRating(widget) {
          var votes = $(widget).data('fsr').rating;
          $(widget).find('.star_' + votes).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
          $(widget).find('.star_' + votes).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 

          }
```

As you see in the code, it is removing the item, however, it is coming back when I move the mouse. Is there a way to make sure when I click on the item to remove it stays removed?

Comment: What does your `outRating` function look like?

Comment: What do your overRating and outRating functions do? Can you share those?

Comment: You are also trying to unbind event listeners from `$(star).attr("class")` which returns a string. You are essentially saying `"star_x ratings_stars ratings_vote".unbind(..)...`

Comment: However, even if you were using it properly, `.unbind()` does not affect inline event handlers. You should be declaring the handlers from within your javascript and using `.on()` and `.off()` respectively.

Comment: I added more code, however, I did the following: $(elem).on('onmouseout'); $(elem).on('onmouseover'); $(elem).off('onmouseout'); $(elem).off('onmouseover'); and I'm still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution..

After trying to figure out why the rating keeps coming back, it was the due to the fact that the outRating function was causing the problem. Here is what I did...

The old outRating function:

```
     function outRating(elem) {
       $(elem).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');  
       setRating($(elem).parent()); 
      }
```

The new outRating function:

```
     function outRating(elem) {
        var star = elem;
        var widget = $(elem).parent();   
        var rating = widget.data('fsr').rating;  

        $(elem).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');  

         if($(star).attr('class') !== 'star_'+ rating + ' ratings_stars') {
           setRating($(elem).parent());  
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but you didn't "bind" the onmouse* events to the element, you added attributes.

You may overwrite the onmouse* attributes with $(elemment).attr('onmouseout', '') or something alike.

and you might want to have a look at https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/